# Is there any R like subset function in Julia?

Tags: r, julia

Consider the iris dataset in R. (available in Julia via **RDatasets** package). Suppose I want to get the observations of "Sepal.Length" and "Petal.Width" for Species "setosa". In R, I can do it by:

> subset(iris, Species=="setosa", select = c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width))

Is there any similar function in Julia for the same job?

Answer (score 2):

```
using RDatasets
iris = dataset("datasets","iris") # typeof(iris) => DataFrames.DataFrame 
subset=iris[iris[:Species].=="setosa",[:PetalLength,:PetalWidth]]
```

Notes(1) refer to [RDatasets.jl](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/RDatasets.jl):

> In order to load one of the data sets included in the `RDatasets`
>   package, you will need to have the **`DataFrames`** package installed.
>   This package is automatically installed as a dependency of the
>   `RDatasets` package if you install `RDatasets` as follows:

```
Pkg.add("RDatasets")
```

Note(2): as `datasets` in `RDatasets` package are of `DataFrame` type, so one can use syntax from [dataframesjl](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subsets.html) to create `Subsets`

EDIT:

As @jverzani commented, `using DataFramesMeta` unveils a set of macros with `SQL` semantics that guides users to write query statements in more familiar styles. e.g the above command would be `@ix(iris, :Species.=="setosa", [:PetalLength,:PetalWidth])`

Comment: Of course it solves the particular problem, but this approach may not be handy more generally, I mean when I want to subset many variable. e.g. consider: 

> subset(iris, Species==c("setosa", "versicolor"), select = c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width))

Comment: You can use it, no matter the count of variables, I can't find the benefit of `R` syntax compare to `DataFrame` one. Perhaps because I am not familiar with `R`. even I count length of two syntax and they are of the same length!

Comment: With the `DataFramesMeta` package you have `@where` to filter cases and `@select` to specify variables. Something like: `@select(@where(iris, :Species .== "setosa"), :SepalLength, :PetalLength)` could be used in one line, or piped via `@linq iris |> where(:Species .== "setosa") |> select(:SepalLength, :PetalLength)`